# Exclude values from a SQL query in Swift

Tags: sqlite, swift

This code is triggering an error saying that `rightAnswer` is `nil`.  It should be very simple; it worked fine until adding in the `namesSoFar` variable and the `and name not in` part of the query.  I also experimented with changing `not in` to `in`, presumably limiting my query to those three values (which I'm certain are in there) and got the same error.

```
namesSoFar = ["Bob", "Susan", "Gordon"]
let querySQL = "SELECT name, picture_name from member_data where picture_name is not ? and name not in ? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: ["None", namesSoFar])
rightAnswer!.next()
```

EDIT:

Still trying to debug.

This works:

```
    let querySQL = "SELECT name, picture_name from member_data where picture_name is not ? and name is ? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: ["None", "Bob"])
```

These don't:

```
    let querySQL = "SELECT name, picture_name from member_data where picture_name is not ? and name in ? ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: ["None", ["Bob"]])
```

or

```
rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: ["None", ("Bob")])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the correct syntax is

```
    let querySQL = "SELECT name, picture_name from member_data where picture_name is not ? and name not in (?, ?) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: ["None", "Bob", "Susan"])
```