# Unpack values in NOT IN SQL query in IOS app

Tags: ios, sqlite

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905419/exclude-values-from-a-sql-query-in-swift) about how to construct a SQL query to exclude certain values in my Swift app.  It didn't get a lot of traction, but I figure out a way that works (maybe there's a better way?)

```
let querySQL = "SELECT name, picture_name from member_data where picture_name is not ? and name not in (?, ?) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: ["None", "Bob", "Susan"])
```

While this works for this case, I don't know how many names I'd want to exclude; it could be 0-10 names (it's a quiz game and I don't want to repeat questions, so each time I push the name to an array). What I *want* is something like:

```
badNames = ("Bob", "Susan") //this can be 0-10 items long

let querySQL = "SELECT name, picture_name from member_data where picture_name is not ? and name not in \(badNames) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: You can play bit more with query string and create it with as many param ('?') as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know Swift, but you should figure this out from this code:

```
var list = @"";
for(NSString *name in badNames)
{
   if(list.length)
   {
      list+=",'"+name+"'";
   }else{
      list+="'"+name+"'";
   }
}
let querySQL = "SELECT name, picture_name from member_data where picture_name is not ? and name not in "+list+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
```

Also be careful that you don't have any ' characters in the Strings or you can get an SQL Injection!

Comment: I guess your answer can work but this is worst way to fill params in sql query because of possible sql-injection

Comment: I know for a fact one person's name _does_ have a ' in it.

Comment: Use the same algorithm to consuct the list of `?`s.